# Is there any connection between $trace(AB^\top B A^\top)$ and $trace(A^\top BB^\top A)$ in general?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, svd

Let $A$ and $B$ be recangular real matrices of the same shape.

> **Question 1.** Is there any connection between $trace(AB^\top B A^\top)$ and $trace(A^\top BB^\top A)$ ?

The answer is probably, No! in general (an exception being when one of $A$ and $B$ is proportional to an orthogonal projection matrix), but maybe I'm missing something.

> **Question 2.** What is a general condition between $A$ and $B$, for which the answer to **Question 1** is affirmative ?

Comment: Thanks for the input. There seems to be a typo. Indeed, $AB$ may not make sense since $A$ and $B$ are rectangular of the same shape.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Disregard my comment.

Comment: A possibly useful observation:
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AB^TBA^T) = \operatorname{tr}([AB^T][AB^T]^T) = \|AB^T\|_F^2,\\
\operatorname{tr}(A^TBB^TA) = \operatorname{tr}([A^TB][A^TB]^T) = \|A^TB\|_F^2 = \|B^TA\|_F^2,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @BenGrossmann  very interesting observation! Thanks!.  May be another equivalent formulation:   Is it true to say: $tr(B^TBA^TA)=tr(BB^TAA^T)$?  tp have this equivalent formulation we use the cyclic property of the trace: $tr(ABC)=tr(BCA)=tr(CAB)$. So puting $ A:=A. B:=B^TB,C:=A^T$ we have $trace(AB^TBA^T)=trace(B^TBA^TA)$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, the problem can equivalently rewritten as you've done (actually, this is the initial form of my problem; I wrote it here in terms of traces to reach a larger audience). Ali Taghavi: Yes, that is indeed correct, and that's what I used to proof my side comment that the answer to **Q1** is affirmative if $A$ or $B$ is proportional to an orthogonal projection matrix.

Comment: Perhaps it might be helpful to consider the case where $A$ and $B$ have the same left and / or right singular vectors ?

Comment: @BenGrossmann One of your own questions from 2019 appears to be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481667

Comment: @Hyperplane Well spotted! I forgot that I had asked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on Ben's observation, given SVDs $A=U\Sigma V'$ and $B = R\Lambda S'$ we have

$$\begin{aligned} 
\|AB'\|_F^2 &= \|U\Sigma V'S\Lambda'R'\|_F^2  = \|\Sigma  V'S\Lambda'\|_F^2 \\
\|B'A\|_F^2 &= \|S\Lambda'R'U\Sigma V'\|_F^2  = \|\Lambda'R'U\Sigma \|_F^2 \\
\end{aligned}$$

from this, if both $V'S$ and $R'U$ are diagonal, both norms are the same. This happens for instance when $S=V$ and $R=U$, i.e. precisely when $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously SVD-decomposable.

Recall that two **square** matrices are [simultaneously diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization) if and only if they commute. It appears there is a similar condition for the existence of a simultaneous SVD decomposition:

[Prove that if $A^TB$ and $AB^T$ are symmetric, then there exist orthogonal $U,V$ such that $UAV^T$ and $UBV^T$ are diagonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481667/prove-that-if-atb-and-abt-are-symmetric-then-there-exist-orthogonal-u-v/3481720#3481720)

However, the cited paper states that:

> Either one (but in general, not both) of the diagonal matrices may be further restricted to have no negative elements

So it is not quite a simultaneous SVD, but close enough for our purposes here.

Comment: Great,  thanks! This is what I suspected (that is that $A$ and $B$ should have same singular vectors, etc.).

Comment: Possible typo: $W \longrightarrow S$.

Comment: @dohmatob fixed